# ESP8266 A way to determine if new session with client

Tags: webserver, esp8266

I have a project where I am using ESP8266 to serve webpages as UI for my application. My application is used to control an audio device. I keep track of certain settings in the UI during session with the client device such as volume, mute status, etc. I have a requirement that when disconnect button is pressed in the UI (this does not disconnect the UI client session it only turns off audio device) the settings need to stay persistent. I already have the saving of persistent data in my application. Also there are three different pages in my app. When switching between pages I need to load persistent data if client is still in same session and has visited the page before or load defaults if it is the first time visiting the page during current session. My question is if there is a way to tell if a page is being loaded for first time during current session with the client?

Comment: There is a thing called cookie. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies first and try to understand the example code (not copy and paste) https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication.ino

Comment: This solution works. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to maintain a session on the web client, you need to use session [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

There is an [example code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication.ino) shows how to set a cookie from an ESP8266 web server.